# Loading and unloading JSON files using AWS Athena

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I'm trying to load, filter and unload some json files using AWS Athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
json_based_table(file_line string)
LOCATION 's3://<my_bucket>/<some_path/';

UNLOAD
(SELECT file_line from json_based_table limit 10)
TO 's3://<results_bucket>/samples/'
WITH (format = 'JSON');
```

Problem is the output is a set of files containing a json per line that has a single key "file_line" who's value is a json line from the original file as a string.

How do I UNLOAD such a table values only? (ignoring the column name I had to create to load the files)

Comment: Can you share sample input rows and outputs that you got. Also expected output you want

Comment: Take any json as input, read it and try to unload it to the same format it was originally

Comment: You need to select/parse columns in in your UNLOAD statement. With out looking at the actual JSON record it is not feasible to provide you with a query to uUNLOAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by choosing

```
WITH (format = 'TEXTFILE');
```

I can get what I want.
Choosing JSON as a format is good for preserving the tabular structure of the table in a file and was a misleading name in this case.